# Android Webview Full Screen Image from DCIM folder

Tags: android, webview

I found several examples but none of them seem to be working for my situation. I want to present a full screen view of an image file from the DCIM folder on the SD Card. Here are the key elements of my code that is not quite working. I am getting a white screen but no image:

webkit is defined in my layout as a WebView.
IMAG0013.jpg is in the DCIM folder on the SD card.

```
String html = ("<html><center><img src=\"IMAG0013.jpg\"></html>");
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/";

browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);

browser.loadDataWithBaseURL(path, html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

I want to present the image with the original dimensional ratio such that it fills the screen as much as possible without stretching or squeezing the perspective maintaining the view of the image with it's original ration of height to width.

Advice?

Comment: What are your permissions and any logcat output please.